# How to fix this angular error "Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):"?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

Just built a brand new Angular App with SASS but when trying to write sass I get the following error

> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js).

This is what I'm running on - `Angular-Cli: 8.2.0`, `Node: 10.16.2`, `NPM: 6.9.0`

I've tried adding a webpack config file in the attempt to try out a solution from a similar issue but instead in a react app.

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /.(ts|tsx)?$/,
            use: [
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: "sass-loader"
                    }
            ],
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            enter code hereinclude: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            exclude: [/node_modules/]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to just be able to write SASS within the angular framework.

Comment: npm rebuild node-sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was simply trying to write scss when having the .sass ext. Easy fix knowing now what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Trying using the below commands

```
sudo npm rebuild node-sass

sudo npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

Comment: using angular 8 (system) 7 (local project) and it works like charm

Comment: npm install --save-dev  --unsafe-perm node-sass   work in my case , on first command i was getting python error